# WPF set DataTemplate on Viewmodel class programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a listbox in WPF that will contain a list of `ResultsViewModel` items, however the actual runtime type of these objects could be

- `CalculateResultsViewModel`,
- `ScenarioResultsViewModel`,
- `GraphResultsviewModel` etc etc,

all of which extend the base abstract class `ResultsViewModel`.

Each of these view models should be rendered differently in the `ListBox` so needs a different `DataTemplate`. I can do that just with XAML easy enough. The difficulty is that when the viewmodels are either "processing" or when they have failed", I need them to display a `DataTemplate` for "processing" or "errored" which I can only so far do with `Triggers`. That however then means I can't use the `DataTemplateSelector` or a basic XAML style.

The only solution I can think of (not clean I know) is to set the `DataTemplate` programmatically in the `SetResult()` method of each viewmodel class, which is what gets called when the processing completes either successfully or with an error. In that `DependencyProperty` I can look at the return code and then programatically set the `DataTemplate` depending on the sucess/failure result. The only problem is I cannot figure out how to

1. Obtain a `DataTemplate` resource from a `ResourceDictionary` just using c# code - bearing in mind Im calling all of this from the viewmodel class, not the window code-behind .xaml.cs file so it doesn't have access to the properties of `Window`
2. having only a handle to the viewmodel class, somehow obtain a reference to the `ListBoxItem` that contains it and then programmatically set the `DataTemplate` on this container.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

you can take the magic with implicit datatemplates

```
<ListBox ItemSource={Binding YourResults}>
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type CalculateResultsViewModel}>
      <Grid></Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type ScenarioResultsViewModel}>
      <Grid></Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type GraphResultsviewModel }>
      <Grid></Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

for "processing" or "errored" viewmodels you can specify a adorner overlay in all yout datatemplates (ok but you must use the triggers)

hope this helps